# detect if the user have an intention to redirect from it's page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if a user has any intention to leave his current page and redirect to any page from my website is their any javascript function that can handle this event I have more than 25 links in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(//user clicks a link )
 confirm("do you want to continue ?"); 

</script>
```

Is their any javascript function that can check if the user click on any link on the page

Comment: `confirm` and `alert` go really badly on user experience. So use these only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will intercept all clicks on links in your page.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    // this.href will be the href of the link they clicked on
    // return false from this function if you want to abort the click on the link
});
```

FYI, unless there are very special circumstances in your page, it's kind of obnoxious to force a user to confirm that they actually want to go to the link they just clicked on.  Can you imagine how terrible the web browser would be if you had to confirm every click.

There is also a generic way to prompt if the user wants to leave your page using the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Note: this is also obnoxious unless there are very special circumstances.

Comment: oh right !!!! i should have thought about this thank you but the onbeforeunload is an event that can only display a message to the user and browsers wont let you check if he want 2 leave the page or stay in it so it can't help me i can do this instead if i want to specify a couple of hyper links to trigger the event i give all my a tag a class and it would be like this : $(".redirected").click(function(){//do something}); that way only the tags with that class wld be triggered

Comment: @Sora - yes if you can narrow it to only some link tags with `$(".redirected").click(fn)`, that would be better.

Comment: yes i just want to check if the user click on a specify links not all of them i can see the annoying result that i can get of it

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Bear in mind that this isn't a normal event - you can't bind to it in the standard way.

To check for values? That depends on your validation framework.

In jQuery this could be something like (very basic example):

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != "" )
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
});
```

Comment: You don't assign a string to `window.onbeforeunload` - you assign a function that returns a string.

Comment: My bad! Has reason. Thanks @jfriend00